# Non Case Sensitive Formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet that has a column that contains values such as "sick" that I want to format with strikethroughs when a button is pressed. I have the following code that works perfect if the cell value is "Sick" but not if the value is "sick" is there a way I can change the code to make it not case sensitive?

```
For Each rng In ws.Range("E1:E" & lastrow)
If rng.Value = "Sick" Then
ws.Range("A" & rng.Row).Resize(1, 2).Font.Strikethrough = True
End If
Next rng
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the line to:

```
 If LCase(rng.Value) = "sick" Then
```

Which will look at the lower case version of the range's value and check it against the lower case string. This ensures that no matter how the range's value is capitalized, lower case will always be compared against lower case.

By the way, VBA also supports a `UCase()` function as well for converting to all upper-case, so your problem could also be solved with:

```
 If UCase(rng.Value) = "SICK" Then
```